# How to schedule automated tasks with power automate desktop

Tags: scheduled-tasks, power-automate-desktop

[I know power automate desktop does not yet have the scheduled tasks feature  but we can achieve the same via a perpetual loop as shown below and then running the flow to until the boundary conditions are met to trigger the action.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMUN6.png)

Please check the below shown image of a desktop flow which Ive created to emulate a daemon

[proposed soultion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMUN6.png)

Answer (score 0):

In this case PAD is the wrong tool for the job, rather look at a windows scheduled task and run something in powershell or command prompt (.bat file)

There is a saying that goes something like:
*"Just because you've got a hammer doesn't mean everyting is a nail"*